# How to properly mutex lock a struct used by trampolines called from C

Tags: rust

I'm using this technique for C code, called from Rust, call a Rust's method back.

```
pub type OnVpnLog = std::sync::Arc<std::sync::Mutex<dyn Fn(*const libc::c_char) + Send + Sync>>;
pub type OnVpnSomething = std::sync::Arc<std::sync::Mutex<dyn Fn(i32) + Send + Sync>>;

struct OVPNClientInner {
    on_vpn_log: Option<OnVpnLog>,
    on_vpn_something: Option<OnVpnSomething>,
}

unsafe extern "C" fn on_log_trampoline(
    buffer: *const libc::c_char,
    user_data: *mut libc::c_void,
) -> libc::c_int {
    let ovpn_client_inner = &mut *(user_data as *mut OVPNClientInner);

    (ovpn_client_inner.on_vpn_log.as_ref().unwrap().lock().unwrap())(buffer);
    0
}

unsafe extern "C" fn on_something_trampoline(
    user_data: *mut libc::c_void,
) -> libc::c_int {
    let ovpn_client_inner = &mut *(user_data as *mut OVPNClientInner);

    (ovpn_client_inner.on_vpn_something.as_ref().unwrap().lock().unwrap())(0);
    0
}
```

In this specific case, I'm calling `on_vpn_log` which is behing a `Mutex`. However, this is not sufficient. Suppose that I call `on_vpn_log` while the function `on_vpn_log` is being replaced by another one. This would lead to undefined behaviour.

Also, the 2 trampolines could in the future with a code update try to access something inside `OVPNClientInner`. We must ensure that `OVPNClientInner` is accessed only once at a time.

One option would be a global static mutex, but that would block one instance of `OVPNClientInner` while another was being updated.

Another option would be to put a mutex inside `OVPNClientInner`:

```
struct OVPNClientInner {
    on_vpn_log: Option<OnVpnLog>,
    on_vpn_something: Option<OnVpnSomething>,
    mutex: Mutex
}
```

But `OVPNClientInner` is shared between C and Rust, so no ffi-unsafe types can be present. Also that mutex could be changed while we try to lock it (maybe we could make it immutable, I don't know)

What would be a good solution here to provide good safety?

Comment: To summarize, you're concerned because these functions can be called from multiple threads simultaneously?

Comment: @kmdreko yes and possibly other problems that I don't even realize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `on_vpn_log` and `on_vpn_something` can be updated and used separately, I'd recommend:

```
pub type OnVpnLog = dyn Fn(*const libc::c_char) + Send + Sync;
pub type OnVpnSomething = dyn Fn(i32) + Send + Sync;

struct OVPNClientInner {
    on_vpn_log: Mutex<Option<Box<OnVpnLog>>>,
    on_vpn_something: Mutex<Option<Box<OnVpnSomething>>>,
}
```

If not, use a single `Mutex` when creating and using the `user_data`:

```
struct OVPNClientInner {
    on_vpn_log: Option<Box<OnVpnLog>>,
    on_vpn_something: Option<Box<OnVpnSomething>>,
}

unsafe extern "C" fn on_log_trampoline(
    buffer: *const libc::c_char,
    user_data: *mut libc::c_void,
) -> libc::c_int {
    let ovpn_client_inner = &*(user_data as *mut Mutex<OVPNClientInner>); // <--------
    
    (ovpn_client_inner.lock().unwrap().on_vpn_log.as_ref().unwrap())(buffer);
    0
}
```

> But `OVPNClientInner` is shared between C and Rust, so no ffi-unsafe types can be present.

I'm not familiar with this API, but typically an opaque `void*` called "user data" is unused by the framework itself. The ffi boundary being `void*` and unused on the C side means there's no concern with using `Mutex` in your structure, you can put almost anything actually.

The only thing you should be concerned about is if what you send is `Sync`, which means its safe to use from multiple threads. Both the implementations above are safe in that regard.

<sup>As an aside, you currently have an `Option` that you're assuming is present. You should either remove it or be sure to handle its absence properly.</sup>